# Link Gitlab with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi I use Gitlab I want to containerize apps that I make and automate deploy so I'm trying to play with Kubernetes on GKE.

I was following [Gitlab's documentation regarding linking Cluster](https://gitlab.spiks.ru/help/user/project/clusters/index#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster)

I tried to create secret through K8S Dashboard (Create, Paste yaml)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: gitlab
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: gitlab
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

press `Upload` and it just swallows it, no errors no new secrets.

Then I tried to add it [through kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/):

`kubectl create -f /tmp/gitlab.yaml` it prints `secret "gitlab" created`
but it didn't

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run a 'kubectl get secrets' to confirm whether secret is created or not?

Comment: You would also benefit from asking for all secrets across all namespaces, since the `gitlab` secret is apparently created, but might not be visible in your currently selected namespace: `kubectl get --all-namespaces secrets`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I tried, nothing.

Comment: @Insightcoder yes, nothing

Answer (score 0):

> `kind: Secret`
>
> `type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token`

I see what's going on here: you're trying to *manually* create a `ServiceAccount` token, when those are designed to be managed by kubernetes, not you, because the token contains a correctly formatted and cryptographically signed JWT.

Independent of that, it's silly to create a service-account-token `Secret` that contains no secret data (s.a.t. always contain 3 bits of data: `ca.crt`, `namespace`, and `token`). Then, even if you did populate that `Secret` with an actual JWT -- which would be very weird -- you'll also want to include the annotation `kubernetes.io/service-account.uid:` containing the UUID of the ``` gitlab``ServiceAccount ``` (which you can find by `kubectl get -o json sa gitlab | jq -r .metadata.uid`)

Reasonable people can differ about whether this is a bug, or a crazy edge case that doesn't hurt anything. I think of this as the equivalent of `INSERT INTO users;` reporting `OK`; sure, it didn't insert anything, but the command was nonsense anyway, so it's hard to get really worked up about things.

Comment: You didn't seem to read the actual question I didn't come up with the idea of manually creating a token, I read on Gitlab's docs, I provided the link. There it says that it will populate secret fields for me (and it did) btw I did figure that out, I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

my bad, I specified `kubernetes.io/service-account.name` to be `gitlab` even though there is no such service account, I replaced it with `default` and everything worked